# C# Common Library

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I'm hoping to find an open source .net common library, but I'm having a hard time finding one.

What I'm looking for a is something that contains : Logging, Caching, String Manipulation, Config Reading, ext?!?.

Do you know if anything like this exists or is this more likely something that I will need to create myself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Microsoft Enterprise Application Blocks

Get it from here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx

Source code here

http://www.codeplex.com/entlib

Comment: String manipilation is in the Regex classes, and the String class, but all the rest is definitely in the application blocks.

Answer (score 7):

- [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) - Built by Microsoft, source code is available
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) - Open source development framework

Answer (score 7):

Kev:

Just a bit more elaboration, I've spent quite a bit of time trying to reuse code from other frameworks:
Here is a breakdown based on feature sets:

Infrastructures frameworks( config, logging, caching, etc)

1. SpringFramework.NET - ( Port of the popular Java SpringFramework )
2. Microsoft Enterprise Library - Microsoft "answer" to SpringFramework.

Frameworks providing ActiveRecord or Ioc(Inversion Of Control) or Code generation:

1. Castle Project 
   http://www.castleproject.org/index.html
2. SubSonic
   http://subsonicproject.com/
3. NetTiers
   http://nettiers.com

Finally, you may find many other smaller libraries, frameworks on CodePlex.com
Some that are of note:

1. CommonLibrary.NET
   http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/
2. DotNet Commons 
   http://dotnetcommons.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

All that is built into the framework, so all you really need is mono.

Comment: Logging and caching are not built into the framework. And what does mono have to do with the question?

Comment: Take a look at the Trace class as the support for writing to the windows event log.  For caching, there are classes available to persist dictionary values.  You asked about open source, hence mono: the open source .Net implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Nido Framework](https://nidoframework.codeplex.com) too

Nido is a code framework, a common project, an architectural pattern, written on Microsoft .NET/C# 4.5, to help software engineers to develop their systems faster.

Other than automatically building/ architecting the back end code for you.. it also help you in

1. Handling of log-in exceptions, display user friendly messages, tracking errors.
2. Tracking changes done to important data items which is also called audit trails
3. Validating records and encrypting sensitive data to protect their privacy
4. Controlling complexity by mean of handling complex problems in one standard way
5. Set standards pattern for coding

Answer (score 0):

Logging - have a look at [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)